# Integrate $f(r,\theta) = r$ over the region between $r = a(1+cos\theta)$ and $r = a$

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

I am asked to integrate the function given in polar coordinates $f(r,\theta) = r$ over the region between $r = a(1+\cos\theta)$ and $r = a$.

My answer is 
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{a} r\cdot r \mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d}\theta + \int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} \int_{0}^{a(1+cos\theta)} r \cdot r \mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d}\theta = \frac{7a^3\pi}{6} - \frac{22 a^3}{9}$$

but the textbook's answer gives

$$\left( \frac{22}{9} + \frac{5 \pi}{6} \right) \cdot a^3.$$

Did I do something wrong?

**EDIT**

I now have the corrected answer

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_{a}^{a(1+cos\theta)} r \cdot r \mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d}\theta = \frac{22a^3}{9} + \frac{\pi a^3}{2}$$

which still disagrees with the textbook. Can anyone see a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your limits are wrong, for example in the first integral you're integrating between $r=0$ and $r=a$ instead of $r=a(1+\cos\theta)$ and $r=a$. It also isn't clear what range you should take for $\theta$, but we note when $\theta=\pi/2$ and $\theta=-\pi/2$ that $a(1+\cos\theta)=a$, so we may be expected to integrate between these limits? Or perhaps the contribution on the left side of the graph should also be included.
[image: Polar plot]

Integration over the two areas bounded by the blue and green lines is simply given by
$$\begin{align}
&\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_a^{a(1+\cos\theta)} f(r,\theta) r \mathrm{d} r \mathrm{d} \theta,
&\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} \int_{a(1+\cos\theta)}^a f(r,\theta) r \mathrm{d} r \mathrm{d} \theta.
\end{align}$$
The first of these gives $a^3\left( \frac{9}{22} + \frac{\pi}{2} \right)$.

Comment: you are correct, and actually there wasn't any error on the formula for f(r,theta). The problem contains an additional information that I hadn't given much attention: the area doesn't contain the origin. That means that the correct way to calculate it is, from the two integrals you wrote, the one on the right.

When I evaluate that, i get 22a^3/9 - pi*a^3/2 (which is still different from the textbook's answer). Do you get the same answer?
Thank you.

Comment: If the area doesn't include the origin you should use the integral I have written on the left, where $r\geq a$. If the integrand is $r$, this integrates to $r^2/2$, which when using the limits will give a factor of $a^2$, so I don't know how you're getting $a^3$? But yes I would have expected a term involving $\pi$ to arise.

Comment: isn't the Jacobiar r dr d\theta? That's why I get r^2. Is that incorrect?

Comment: There was a \pi on the textbook's answer, forgot to add that. For the integral on the left, I got 22a^3/9+a^3*\pi/2

Comment: Yes you're right the Jacobian, which is $r$, should be included, I'll edit my answer. Your wording made it a little ambiguous. I get the same answer as you.

Comment: I just made an edit in the post Siwel, please let me know if you agree. And thatnk you in advance with your help, I appreciate that!

Comment: @bru1987 Please don't alter the original question in an edit, I have suggested an edit which avoids doing that. The only lack of clarity came from not specifying it being a function in polar coordinates, which I also added in. Note you can format maths in comments by enclosing it with single $ symbols.

Comment: ok noted, won't do that anymore. Thank you a lot, best regards.